# How to always show current refresh rate of my Mac on screen (MacBookPro18,3)

Tags: macos, display, applications

My MacBook Pro has a 120Hz display, and supposedly ProMotion should decrease the refresh rate down to 24Hz when nothing is happening to save battery.

I installed a Ubersicht widget that constantly moves around, resulting in my screen always running at full refresh rate, draining the battery significantly.

I need an app that tells me the screen refresh rate **at this exact moment**, whether it is down to 24hz or up at 120hz (or somewhere in between like 69 or 34.)

I looked up for "app that shows refresh rate on Mac" but all search results I get is "hold down 'option' key to show refresh rate in settings" which is not what I want.

I'm looking for something like Nvidia's GeForce Experience in-game overlay on Windows where you can set a FPS counter at the bottom left of the screen to show current refresh rate by heading to Performance options in it's settings.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Quartz Debug" app provided by Apple does this. It shows a live FPS meter.

[image: quartz debug fps meter screenshot]

It's part of "Additional Tools for XCode" and you're required to login with your Apple ID to download them.  You can find the latest one here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=additional%20tools%20XCode